# Can't disable/stop GbpSv Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, windows-8.1, permission-denied

I'm trying to set a windows process called "GbpSv" to disabled and although my user is administrator, all the commands are disabled.

Ex:

```
C:\Users\Andre>sc config "GbpSv" start=disabled
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:
Access is denied.

C:\Users\Andre>net stop "GbpSv"
The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service
```

[image]

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Trying to kill the process:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GbPlugin>tasklist | FindStr Gbp
GbpSv.exe                      104 Services                   0     16.520 K
GbpSv.exe                     5324 Console                    1     13.448 K

C:\Program Files (x86)\GbPlugin>taskkill /pid 104
ERROR: The process with PID 104 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).

C:\Program Files (x86)\GbPlugin>taskkill /f /pid 104
ERROR: The process with PID 104 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't merely stop it like that. You'll have to purge it completely from your machine because it's a security plugin that some banks provide in order to secure your access to their internet banking services. Therefore it's very well protected from malicious removal by rogue apps.

Here's how you can remove it:

First you'll have to delete the Program files\Gbplugin folder. I deleted it by booting into Linux (you could use an Ubuntu live CD), mounting the Windows partition and deleting it. Logging in as a Windows administrator or into Secure Mode should do the trick as well.

But in order to get rid of the Gpb Service, Gbplugin and Warsaw (its companion app, written by "Gas Tecnologia"), you'll have to delete all of their entries on the Regedit. Just open regedit, press ctrl+f, look for "Gpb", "Gbplugin", "Gpbsv" and "Warsaw" and delete the entries. Be careful not to delete unrelated stuff!

You can uninstall Warsaw from the Control Panel. Make sure you delete the DLLs left on your local folder (you can easily find them with the Windows Explorer Search).

On the next reboot the service should be disabled.

If you don't uninstall it and delete the Regedit entries mentioned above, it will keep reinstalling Gpb silently over and over again. So leave no stone unturned.

Obs: To reboot into secure mode using Windows 8.1, hold the Shift key while choosing the restart option from the "Power Options".